# error LNK2019 "unresolved external symbol" when passing a function as a parameter

Tags: c++, function-pointers, typedef, linker-errors

I'm trying to pass a function as an argument in C++. I keep getting a LNK2019 unresolved external symbol error.

I've read about these, and have fixed these in the past, but i can't figure out what i'm doing wrong here.

## main.ccp

The error seems to occur with my TreeItemType reference within my display function.

```
include "PhoneBook.h"  
include "PhoneEntry.h"  
include "bst.h"   
using namespace std;  
using namespace p04NS;  

void display(TreeItemType& item);

int main() {

    PhoneEntry test = PhoneEntry("first", "last", "618-580-0680");
    bst * tree = new bst();

    TreeItemType foo = TreeItemType(); // test type reference, no error

    tree->insert(test);

    tree->inorder(display);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void display(TreeItemType& item){
    cout << "hello worlds!";
}
```

## bst.h

The TreeItemType typedef is defined here.

```
namespace p04NS {

    typedef PhoneEntry TreeItemType;
    typedef string KeyType;

    // Pointer to a function that can be used to display the item.
    typedef void (*FunctionType)(const TreeItemType& item);

    class bst { //some codez  }

}
```

## Debugging notes:

I tried using this type in main, and received no error. Also, whether it errors whether or not i comment out the usage of the function. So it appears to be an issue with my function definition, and not its usage.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include the **complete** error that you're getting.  You've omitted the part that tells you *what symbol is unresolved*

Comment: Sorry, maybe i should of been more descriptive. I was trying to keep things as simple as possible. This is resolved now though, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
void display(TreeItemType& item){
```

and

```
typedef void (*FunctionType)(const TreeItemType& item);
```

Spot the difference? Hint, it starts with the letter 'c'.

However as given this code should not compile. So you must have some other problem too. Always post real code.

Comment: OIC! Now it all makes sense. Thanks, i think i just needed that extra eye!

Answer (score 0):

I usually get this error when I haven't written a function definition, only the declaration. for example, when I comment out the implementation for void AITank::obstructed() like so:

```
//void AITank::obstructed()
//{
//    // some code here
//}
```

but I've called that function somewhere (and have still got void obstructed(); in the AITank.h file)

I get:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall AITank::obstructed(void)" (?obstructed@AITank@@$$FQAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Game::play(void)" (?play@Game@@$$FQAEXXZ)

Have a look at what the line says, and see if that tells you which function you're missing.